# How do I check a row for a condition, and then once found change subsequent rows until a second condition is met in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, signal-processing

I'm struggling with some time series data in Pandas.  Basically I have a time series of hourly snow depth change over 15 days.  Its VERY jumpy and I would like to remove the spurious jumps (see graph of raw data linked).[Snotel_TimeSeries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ezU.png)

The data is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
snofall_df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':['12/13/2021 2:00', '12/13/2021 3:00', '12/13/2021 4:00','12/13/2021 5:00', '12/13/2021 6:00', '12/13/2021 7:00', '12/13/2021 8:00', '12/13/2021 9:00','12/13/2021 10:00', '12/13/2021 11:00'], 'Raw': [25, 25, 79, 134, 134, 134, 134, 25, 26, 27]}
```

The best way I could think of to remove these jumps is to calculated a rate of change between each observation (since its hourly data this ends up being the hourly snowfall rate) using

```
snofall_df['Rate']=snofall_df['Raw'].diff()
```

This gives me the following table:

| DateTime | Raw | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ######### | 25 | n/a |
| ######### | 25 | 0 |
| ######### | 79 | 54 |
| ######### | 134 | 55 |
| ######### | 134 | 0 |
| ######### | 134 | 0 |
| ######### | 134 | 0 |
| ######### | 25 | -109 |
| ######### | 26 | 1 |
| ######### | 27 | 1 |

I would like to find all rows where the rate of change jumps unrealistically (like it would be crazy to have a snowfall rate of 10 inches in an hour!) and then set the values of snow depth to "n/a" UNTIL the snowfall rate decreases unrealistically (like the -109 in the rate column) while leaving all other values alone.

Basically I would like an "Adj_Depth" column added to the table like this:

| DateTime | Raw | Rate | Adj_Depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ######### | 25 | n/a | 25 |
| ######### | 25 | 0 | 25 |
| ######### | 79 | 54 | n/a |
| ######### | 134 | 55 | n/a |
| ######### | 134 | 0 | n/a |
| ######### | 134 | 0 | n/a |
| ######### | 134 | 0 | n/a |
| ######### | 25 | -109 | 25 |
| ######### | 26 | 1 | 26 |
| ######### | 27 | 1 | 27 |

I have tried things like

```
snofall_df['Adj_Depth]` = np.where((snofall_df['Rate'] >= 10) | (snofall_df['Rate'].shift(-1) <= -10), np.nan, snofall_df['Raw'])
```

This gets rid of all values where the rate increases or decreases to fast but it leaves all the high spurious points in between. I'm trying to avoid iterating over the column if possible as with large datasets this becomes quite cumbersome.

Does anyone know a "pythonic" way of doing the above operation within Pandas?  Thanks so much for any help anyone can provide on this.

Comment: Would it be crazy to have 48 inches of snowfall in 3 days? Where I am, that actually happened (and is still).

Comment: That would not be crazy at all! But 59 inches in an hour would be a bit suspect!

Comment: Haha, yes, that would not be realistic! :D

Comment: the way you got `Adj_Depth` is a good idea =D. Then why don't you use something like `df.fillna['Adj_Depth'](snofall_df['Adj_Depth'].median())`. I Believe at the end the depth can't be too much different from the median.

Comment: My problem is that the code I use to get Adj_Depth only puts n/a on the rows where there is an unrealistic change in rate...not all rows in between which is what I need...the Adj_Depth was more of an example of what I would like...I probably should have been more clear :)